# Typescript and the Chrome Debugger (F12 Tools)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, typescript

I am trying to understand how the Chrome Debugger (F12 tools) connects things up to allow Typescript debugging.

I had a simple project that was working fine.  And I decided to put some of my files a single folder deeper.  (I took my test.html, test.ts and the generated test.js and put them in a folder called "views/test" where before they were just in "views".)

When I did that, the ts file stopped showing up in the list of files in the debugger.  I could get it to show up if I mapped the network level folders to my files.  But breakpoints would not work.

When I rolled back to the flatter file structure the ts file is there and can be debugged against.

**So, why did it not allow me to see and debug against the ts file when it was nested one level deeper?**

Note: I did several "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"s while testing this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might need to regenerate your source maps, as those will reference specific segments in the specific TypeScript source file. If you move your `.ts` files without recreating the source maps, then the Chrome debugger won't know where to look for the TypeScript source.

Comment: How is that done?  I am recompiling my typescript to javascript each run.  Is that different?

Comment: What flags are you passing to tsc? Take a look [the compiler docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options), paying close attention to the `--mapRoot` and `--sourceMap` flags.